# Eclipse CDT, creating dialogs

Tags: user-interface, dialog, eclipse-cdt

I have installed (on Linux) and configured CDT successfully and now I need to create a dialog-based application with Eclipse CDT (C++).
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give Qt a try: http://qt.nokia.com/developer/eclipse-integration

It is Open Source and cross-platform (supports Windows, Linux and Mac OS X)

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse CDT is simply an IDE for C/C++ projects. It's not a library as such, but a development tool. You can read more at: http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/   If you start there, I'm sure you can find stuff on creating a GUI-based program.